# Under the rug footer with full height 100%

Tags: jquery, css, footer

So I've been trying to find a way to make a footer appear as the page scroll down I found something that is almost similar to what I want to do here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Me2Dz/1/

But look at the #content and #footer css.

```
#content { margin-bottom: 200px; }

#footer { height: 200px; }
```

Except the only thing I'd like to add is to make my footer height and width 100%. In the example I saw that the margin-bottom of the #content equals to the footer height but how would I do it if the footer height is always going to be 100% of the window?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would a footer be 100% height of the window? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am making a website with the footer as 100% height because it will be some sort of Outro to the website. It's a wedding website.

Comment: Then an alternative method would be required. Set the main content to be 100% tall and put the footer under it. Wouldn't that work - http://jsfiddle.net/50ytzt4m/k?

Comment: That's almost what I want to achieve! Except is there a way to do that but the #cotnent area already has a defined height? Would javascript be a solution to calculate the windows height according to different screen size?

Comment: Just wrap the #content with the 100% high div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Me2Dz/14/

Add margin-bottom: 100%; to the #content and height: 100%; to the #footer so they look like this

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:1500px;
    margin-bottom:100%;
    background-color:#123456;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that's exactly what I was looking for. did not know margin-bottom: 100%: was possible. many thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

on #footer remove line:

z-index:-1;

it's behind.

Comment: If we remove the z-index the footer would always be visible